# HTTP Server invalid request/connection throttling

Tags: .net, http, sockets

I have a custom HTTP server.

When F5 is held down in a browser the server gets slammed with requests.

How can I detect and limit these (or any other) invalid connections?

It seems that I would have to record, for each incoming IP, the length of time between each request and whether or not the request was valid.  If a certain number of invalid requests are received in a certain period time, I would simply disconnect (or ban) all further connections coming from that IP for a certain period of time.

Does anyone have any articles, pointers or tips on this subject?

Comment: Not sure, but +1 to cancel it out!  ;)

Comment: You make get a better answser on http://serverfault.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When he posted on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/http-server-invalid-request-connection-throttling , I suggested that he might get a better response here because the question deals with a custom http server. Writing a webserver isn't really on-topic for webmasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be careful about throttling your server based on IP address - some large corporations proxy all of their HTTP traffic through a single IP address (or small range of IP addresses) so what may appear as an "attack" from a single IP address could actually be many different people behind the same firewall or proxy.